# Stack.Screen expo option headerLeft is not showing

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

function LogoTitle() {
  return (
    <Image
      style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
      source={require("../assets/icon.png")}
    />
  );
}

export default function Home() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(10);

  return (
    <>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          headerTitle: (props) => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => setCount((c) => c + 1)}
              title="Update count"
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Text>Cout: {count}</Text>
    </>
  );
}
```

Button  in the <Stack.Screen> is not showing, is see only the content in Text
i don't see headerTitle and HeaderRight
i wrote the code like in documentation

Answer (score 1):

Button is not a complete JSX component, I faced the similar issue, wrap the Button in a view or use touchable Opacity